# how to write 301 redirect rule when urls have the same base

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I have troubles writing 301 redirect rules in ht access. I can't find the right syntax.

My problem is that two rules

```
Redirect 301 /lessons/                  https://example.com/lessons/piano/
Redirect 301 /lessons/classical/violin/  https://example.com/lessons/vilolin/
```

they redirect all to

```
https://example.com/lessons/piano/
```

I guess it's because the first part of url is the same, what is the correct syntax ?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do let us know from which url to which url you want to redirect more clearly? And after redirection which file in backend it should be served?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `RedirectMatch` rather than using `Redirect` in this case to use regular expressions in matching the URLs. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RedirectMatch 301 /lessons/?$            https://example.com/lessons/piano/
RedirectMatch 301 /lessons/classical/violin/?$  https://example.com/lessons/vilolin/
```